# SignalR Variables are being Reset

Tags: javascript, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

With my SignalR program I had my client call a server side method. My global variables weren't working correctly so I did a quick little test and I figured out that the global variables seemed to be reset every single time, I was wondering what I was doing wrong and if I could keep my variables from being reset.

JavaScript Method:

```
  $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $('#send').click(function () {
                chat.server.send(0, document.getElementById("Name").value, document.getElementById("Content").value);//send eventually calls broadcastArray

            });
        });
```

Hub Method:

```
int i = 0;
    public void BroadcastArray()
    {
        var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();
        hubContext.Clients.All.broadcastArray(messageArr);
        i = i + 1;
    }
```

No matter how many times I called the method `i` was always returned as 1, how can I stop the variables from being reset? Is there a way to do this in the hub class or would I store my variables in a different class? I'm not quite sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I would do is put it in a try/catch to see if its throwing an error before it gets to that line. I could be silently throwing an exception if your hubcontext is not getting returned properly.

Secondly is your hub a static class? Without seeing how you are setting up your hub its hard to tell what could be going wrong.